# Search Logic using database in Qt

Tags: sql, postgresql, qt, search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBysJ.png)

can any one help me with how to write logic to search button. Qt based one..
I have stored value in back end database. and showing the search in table view widget of my gui. how can i write query if user ender and searching any of these one field or h=

```
SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE (username LIKE '%' OR username LIKE 'Sam') AND (userrole LIKE 'Admin' OR userrole LIKE '%');
```

I have tried to retrieve like this, i know it'll give all the values in the data.how can i write query for this?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Please provide a sample of the data you have, and what you would like to query from it

Comment: please find my image, you may get the point